# How to handle "I'd say" when turning into reported speech

Tags: indirect-speech

How can I rewrite this sentence as reported speech?

> I'd say a lot depends on the student.

I can't figure out what is going to happen with *would*?

Comment: Just add *that* before the reported speech: "I'd say that ..."

Comment: If you're not providing a quotation, but a narrative, then it would be this: *She said she'd say a lot depends on the student.* (Or whatever pronoun the person uses.)

Comment: 'I'd say' here is a sentence-connector/introducer, equivalent to 'In my opinion', so 'rewriting the sentence as reported speech' doesn't make sense.

Comment: He opined that a lot depends on the student.

Answer (score 1):

'Would + verb' either stays the same (if it is a more general statement), or can, but does not need to, change into 'would have + past participle' (if we are hypothesising).

'I **would buy** it if I had the money,’ he said. -> He said he **would buy** it if he had the money.

‘I’**ll help** you if you need a volunteer’ / ‘I’**d help** you if you needed a volunteer.’ -> He said he **would have helped** us if we’d needed a volunteer.

See here: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pl/grammar/british-grammar/reported-speech-indirect-speech

However, I think best option would be to omit 'I'd say' to avoid repeating 'said/say'. When reporting statements it is advised to follow the meaning of a verb than its form. Again, see the link above:

She said, ‘You **must** pay by 30th April.’ -> She said we **had to** pay by 30th April.

‘It **must** be awful to live in such a noisy place,’ she said. -> She said it **must** be awful to live in such a noisy place.

So my choice would be:

'He said that (in his opinion) a lot depends/depended on the student.'

Comment: Yes; the question smacks of an exercise involving a tricky case where an arcane rule has to be used to generate the 'technically correct' answer, but where that answer sounds preposterous (and thus the examiners should be replaced according to Orwell's Sixth Law). Your answer, or 'He said that he thought a lot depended on the student', is the idiomatic choice (and thus '_correct_ correct').

Comment: Yes! 'He said that he thought...' - that's even better.

Comment: I'll not upvote the answer, as it doubtless doesn't accord with the spirit of the (exam?) question. But your answere certainly needs to be here in this thread; ELU is 'English Language and (standard) Usage', _not_ Examination Legalistic Unidiomaticity.

Answer (score 0):

He said, "I'd say a lot depends on the student."

When reported:
He said he would say that a lot depended on the student. 
Old style : He said he would have said that a lot depended on the student.

Comment: Yes, we don't know whether OP intends the quotes to specify the spoken words or not.

Comment: @Edwin, Yes agree with your views.

Comment: I'd add one more solution. "He said he'd say a lot depends on the student" - if still a lot depends on the student

Comment: +1 for common sense. “I’d say” is a mannerism, somewhat like starting off  a sentence with “Basically”. When you report it exactly, you let the reader “see” the speaker and their intent more clearly. Readers who know the speaker will know how to interpret the words. Those who don’t will at least get the speaker’s actual words and not the reporter’s interpretation. That said, if the writer **intends** to convey the reporter’s interpretation (which is totally valid), any number of expressions can be used.